# Différence entre les mots « bien » et « bon »

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces mots ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens ?

> Il est bon.

mais

> Il parle bien.

Comment: Pour poser une question différente, n'édite pas une question existante, [pose une nouvelle question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: merci a votre pursuivre